# EF Core include an ICollection<T> with a filter on the collection's referenced object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I need a query that will return all `Driver`s including the `Departures` collection for each, where each collection is filtered by properties of the `Departure`.

This query:

```
// id supplied by HTTP POST
var driver = await _context.Drivers
  .Include(d => d.Departures.Where(dd => dd.Acknowledged == false))
  .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Generates an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'd => {from
>   Departure dd in d.Departures where ([dd].Acknowledged == False) select
>   [dd]}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property
>   access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related
>   data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

What am I not understanding?

## Model

- `Driver` has many `Departures`
- `Departure` has one `Driver`

Driver:

```
public class Driver
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Departure> Departures { get; set; }
}
```

Departure:

```
public class Departure
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Boolean Acknowledged { get; set; }
    ...
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF Core 2.0 with VS Studio for Mac.

Comment: @ivanStoev I'm not sure you've picked a good duplicate, because the only answer there is a link-only that leads to an off-site discussion. Is there perhaps a better candidate?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Filtered includes are one of the most asked EF features. And the answer is always - not supported. There is no chance it to be implemented in EF6, but there are plans for EF Core, so the answer I've picked is IMO the right one at this time - with links to EFC issue tracker. Keep in mind that many EF6 workarounds do not work in EF Core, or work differently in specific EFC version. Sometimes Includes are ignored, sometimes not. Also projection tricks might or might not work. Personally I see no other option than monitoring the EFC status or switch to using DTO/ViewModels.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But you are right - there must be a lot of duplicates. If you have better one, I'll be happy to use it. Actually we have another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440972/net-core-2-ef-include for closing. These are coming 2-3 daily :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I recently discovered a cool feature - the edit link in the bottom-right corner of the "This question already has an answer" box. It lets you add new duplicates as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter departures on the `Driver` object itself, but you could filter them on the return value:

```
var driverAndDepartures = await _context.Drivers
  .Select(d => new {
      Driver = d
  ,   UnacknowledgedDepartures = d.Departures.Where(dd => !dd.Acknowledged).ToList()
  })
  .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Once you get `driverAndDepartures` back and `null`-check the result, you can get the driver through `driverAndDepartures.Driver` and his unacknowledged departures though `driverAndDepartures.UnacknowledgedDepartures` field.

If you try getting `driverAndDepartures.Driver.Departures` you would read the whole unfiltered collection of departures.