# .NET CORE 2 EF Include

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using new .net core and EF.

I need help with include linq command. I have some 1:N models and if the collection contais some data marked like deleted I do not want to include them.

How to do it?

```
var company = await _context.Company
                .Include(y => y.Administrators)
                .Include(y => y.CompanyPartTimers)
                .Include(z => z.WorkPlaces)
                .Include(z => z.Requirements)
                .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

If I add the condition

```
.Include(z => z.WorkPlaces).Where(x=>x.WorkPlaces.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted))
```

It doesn't work. How to write this correctly?

Next thing is I have IDeletable Interface and it would be better if I had some custom linq expression and could do for ex.

```
.Include(z => z.WorkPlaces).GetNonDeleted()
```

Does anyone know how to do it?
I tryed something like this

```
public static class LinqExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetActive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class, IDeletable
        {
            return source.Where(x => x.IsDeleted);
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Change the x=>x.WorkPlaces.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted) to x=>x.WorkPlaces.Any(x=>!x.IsDeleted)

Comment: `"It doesn't work"` Do you get an error? A different result than expected?

Comment: it is compile error

Comment: @JardaLanger, did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes I used tha way in the link bellow using Query Filter
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure a **Query Filter** in your DbContext.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
            .HasQueryFilter(admin => !EF.Property<boolean>(admin, "IsDeleted"));
```

should do the trick

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Answer (score 3):

You should change the inner condition using `Any` instead of `Where`, as:

```
.Include(z => z.WorkPlaces)
.Where(x => x.WorkPlaces.Any(y => !y.IsDeleted))
```

Comment: Also works great for non-boolen fields, for example:
.Where(x => x.WorkPlaces.Any(y => y.Id == 1))